# Reduce number of characters in a String

Tags: java, android, algorithm, encoding, sms

In an Android app that I'm making, when a specific text is entered, its encoded according to a specific algorithm. Then it should be sent as a text message to another device containing the same app with which the encoded text can be decoded. The encoding and decoding parts are working well, but when encoded, it produces a really long `String`. For example,

When the text "Hello World!" is encoded, it produces the String below:

```
zN6xdwB8486d6I6I6T1p5B6T7N6I6x2z1reIWPTp
```

So as this is going as a text message, an average text would produce an extremely long `String`. So is there any way that this encoded `String` can be reduced to a reasonable size? Or any other way I can send this as a text message (as a Serialized Java object (if that's possible in Android) or another way)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try not encoding it.

Comment: Does this have to be cryptographically secure? By what means is it being encoded?

Comment: @Wug That's not possible, as one of the main points in the app is encoding the entered text... :D

Comment: @Wug Yes, it has to be as secure as possible. I just wrote an algorithm myself that will swap character according to a pattern with a key and then merge the key along with the swapped-out text.

Comment: For security reasons its better to use existing crypto algorithms rather than developing your own (unless you know what you are doing)

Comment: Use a real encryption algorithm, your algorithm does nothing but hide the data to someone glancing at it.  You're going to be very limited using SMS to carry payloads, consider using a regular internet connection.   If you have to use sms, you'll need to split large messages into pieces and send lots of them.  you'll need to make sure they arrive in order and that none are dropped.  you also can't just send the key.  I think you're in over your head.

Comment: This should be tagged encryption but it's not clear what tag I should remove.

Comment: @Wug The idea of hiding the data to someone _is_ the whole point of this. And I said _SMS_ for a reason, and not just because it came to my head first. And I think you should be more polite with your comments, otherwise I _may_ have to flag you.

Comment: @Roshnal: unless you use a proper encryption scheme, you're only hiding things from people who don't care enough to try to figure out what is being hidden from them.  You are also trying to send messages over a medium with a 140 character limitation, when the algorithm you're using to obfuscate them almost quadruples the message length.  I'm being realistic, not rude.

Comment: @Wug Sorry, my bad. Every encoding algorithm I looked at, uses some kind of key and often uses even more characters than my way. Is there any algo you know that will suit me? Sorry again...

Answer (score 2):

try to use [Huffman code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) to compress the data.

Comment: I think that will produce an even longer `String` than the encoded one. Remember: size is _not_ the problem. The number of characters _is_.

Comment: size *is* the number of characters. if you use Huffman you could encode a few characters into one.

Comment: How does SMS handle non-ascii characters?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any general way to reduce any string to a string that has a smaller number of characters.  This should intuitively make sense- if you're trying to map 1,000,000 strings onto 100,000 strings there are going to be duplicates.

Furthermore, you run into additional problems if you're trying to keep others from telling what the data you're sending is- you need to make an informed cryptographic decision.  **Do NOT make your own encryption algorithm.**

So more information is needed in order for us to provide any useful information.  Will you be using a subset of the possible strings?

Comment: +1 @Roshnal no time to waste for reinvent encryption/compression algorithm, look around and imagine the time and the energy to do such jobs

Comment: @cl-r Every existing algorithm I saw, uses some kind of key and often increase the number of characters to even more than my way. So anything you know that wouldn't do this?

Comment: if you find a cryptographic algorithm that suits you you should be able to convert the results into the same number of characters...  do you have an example of that problem?

Comment: @airza Any algorithm you already know? I'm a bit stuck finding that uses the same number of characters...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like SMS can carry binary data, so you might be better off using AES or something similar.  You can probably configure it to use an IV of something static and a key generated from a password (that the person on the other end would share).  You could huffman code the string before sending it as well, which would shrink it further, possibly extending the maximum length of your message beyond 140 characters.  It would look something like this:

```
For sending:

input string --> compressed blob --> encrypted blob --> SMS
                                 |
                                  -> known encrypt params 

For receiving:

SMS --> encrypted blob --> compressed blob --> original string
                         |
   known encrypt params -^
```

You might sometimes bypass the compression step.  Some strings don't compress well, and there is a little bit of overhead associated with compression, so under some circumstances, it might make the string larger.

The encryption parameters would constitute overhead if they were left in the encrypted blob.  (The algorithm, the IV, the padding scheme, etc).  If you use one set of these every time, you can just hardcode them into the program and you won't need to send them every time.

Comment: I'm new to this cryptography, so can you please explain to me a bit what "AES", "IV", "the padding scheme" mean? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: AES stands for "advanced encryption standard".  AES is cryptographically secure, and if done in specific ways, will encrypt data to data of an identical size.  I'm not familiar with encryption on android, though I have done it in java (I'm not sure if it's exactly the same though).  You can probably find existing examples of how to use AES to encrypt data on android already on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some small algo to decode your string.

or you can implement simple algo like this

`originalString = "hello";`

each character+1 ex:  a = b, b=c....etc or

each character=3 ex   a = d, b=h....

`encodedString ="ifmmp"`

So **number of character will be as it is** and you will decode your string

Comment: Adding 13 is much more secure.

Comment: There's no value added by this algorithm though.  It doesn't change the size of the string or obscure it in any meaningful way.

Comment: I used this in earlier versions of my app, but its not secure enough. Need something more tighter/harder to decode to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You have 26+26+10 ASCII characters needing 6 bits and the possibility to transform char(short of 2 bytes) in

String "012345678901234567890" use 21 chars or 42 bytes, can be migrated in a 2 concantenaed `long` of 16 bytes.

But as @elyashiv said, using good algorythm is the better way.

**EDIT**

A-Aa-z0-9 are characters of your string :
they can be transfomed in 0->61 digit coded on 6 bits

so you can add them in a long with <<6 each time. the last character (11th) is splitted, and begin the second long.

You have to find a transmetter on byte.

If you String chars are needed for messaging, you will be obliged to use octal, and skip the first non printable characters. so you will can put 7 numbers in a long (with <<7 decal bit).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? And if you can, please provide a link to a suitable algorithm that will apply to this case. Thanks